# UICollectionView size to fit content

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview

I'm trying to implement a `UICollectionView` with custom, auto-sizing cells.
In one of the cell's type I want to use second `UICollectionView` that will hold varying number of elements. I want this second collection to disable scrolling and resize to show all elements inside.

What I achieved for now looks like:
green - main collectionView,
yellow - cell,
pink - cell's content (UICollectionView with more cells :D)

[image]

As you can see, the main cells have constant size and one can scroll secondary cells inside them. Main cells should be varying size to fit all the secondary cells inside them.

My configuration of UICollectionViews:

```
//firstCollectionView
firstCV!.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "FirstCellID", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: monthsCollectionCellReuseIdentifier)
firstCV.dataSource = self
firstCV.delegate = self

if let cvl = firstCV.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 100)

//secondary collectionView does not use autosize for cells, just:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSizeMake(50, 50)
}
```

Comment: for second Collection do , width = collectionviewsize/no of cells you want

Comment: It's possible to use: monthCollectionView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(numOfCells*cellWidth+sumOfInsets).active = true, but it's still doing the job manually.